# Entity Framework: Exclude a navigation property

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I'd like to retrieve an entity which has several navigation properties. I do not want to retrieve one of them and I didn't find a way to achieve this.

Here's my model:

[image: Imgur]

Full size image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x09Cw.jpg

I want to retrieve all navigation properties of a Session entity except Discussions.
So I did:

```
        using (var context = new ModelContainer())
        {
            context.Database.Log = msg => Trace.WriteLine(msg);
            var session = await
                context.SessionSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Identifier == sessionIdentifier);
            var result = await Json(session).ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken());
            return ResponseMessage(result);
        }
```

But I would expect from Entity Framework to have a method which excludes fields of an entity.

Comment: didn't get you really. By default EF will exclude those navigation properties. What you are trying to do BTW?

Comment: Just `Include()` the ones you need and you won't fetch the rest. If you have trouble with circular references use DTO's

Comment: @Rahul I want to select my Session entity, but it comes with all its navigation properties (including Discussions that I don't want to retrieve). So I'd like to find a way to exclude a navigation property. If I do context.SessionSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...), my request will select everything.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Is Include() interfers with lazy loading? (Sorry, I'm new to EF)

Comment: @bbougot Include is used for [Eager Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some research into the different kinds of models.  You are working with a data model, but want to project into a DTO, probably to be used as a ViewModel.  Also, look into using AutoMapper to help converting between the different models.  It makes life MUCH easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
          var session = await
                context.SessionSet.Select(a => new
                {
                    Host = a.Host,
                    Identifier = a.Identifier,
                    Destination = a.Destination,
                    Positions = a.Positions,
                    Sentinelles = a.Sentinelles,
                    Id = a.Id,
                    Code = a.Code,
                    Notifications = a.Notifications,
                    Status = a.Status,
                    Transportation = a.Transportation
                }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Identifier == sessionIdentifier);
            var result = await Json(session).ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken());
```

Comment: Which is a projection into an anonymous DTO. For documentation and interoperability purposes, you may want to extract a concrete type and map to that.